# AC current through induction on both sides

Tags: electromagnetism

When you rotate a coil in a magnetic field one side cuts downwards the other cuts upwards.

When you move a piece of wire up and down you get an AC current or pdf which you can see on a voltmeter as the needle oscillates between 0 and x volts.

My questions as the coil rotates as said it goes up and down. inducing voltages in what seems to me in equal but opposite directions through opposite poles at the same time speed etc. What is the net effect why does not one side of the cutting through the coil oppose or cancel the other side of cutting...

Comment: As long as the total flux trough the loop area changes (e.g. because of inhomogeneity of the field) you get an induced voltage. If you were to move a loop trough a completely homogeneous field, you wouldn't see an induced voltage.

Comment: When you rotate a coil in a magnetic field the leading edge from both sides of the coil advance through the same magnetic flux but in opposite directions so the resulting EMF will combine, not cancel.